# Cant get Import my existing android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

when I try to Import my existing Android project, it appears:

"Failed to read the project desription file(.project) for "myProject". The file has been
changed on disk and it now contains invalid information.  The project will not function
properly untill the description file is restored to a valid state."

note that : I moved my .classpath and .project file to another folder for another purpose, but again i put these file on the same directory as before.

This problem happening after I deleted my Project from Eclipse. but I didn't check the "Delete project contents from disc" checkbox. but I don't know , why I cant use my project now :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with General -> import existing projects into workspace rather than Android -> existing projects into workspace

Comment: just change the whole project file and place some other directory and restart eclipse and try with import...

Answer (score 0):

you just simply right click on ur

> project > Android Tools > fix project property

or i think you deleted your project from workspace..if you have deleted from workspace it will not open your project cause you deleted permenatly deleted.

i should be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Delete your project from Eclipse, but not from disc space, and then do this:

`Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace`